# vba values is missed after copy

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy all Information from one workbook with calculation to another without the ones. The Problem arises then i save the new file, close and open again. Some Information is missed. This is exactly information which was introduced   as references from a different sheet in the original file. 
What can I add to my code to avoid this Problem? Is it possible just copy not only values but everything?

```
Sub Doc()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
  Sheets(Array("Introduction_Page", "Observation_Overview", "ICS Analysis", "ICS Table")).Copy

   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     ws.Cells.Copy
     ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Cells(1, 1).Select
     ws.Activate
    Next ws

  Cells(1, 1).Select                       
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you're having. Could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: I see you copy your workbook `ws.cells.copy` but I don't see where you paste them? This code doesn't really do much of anything, I don't think.

Comment: I have a tool in VBA, where all calculations are performed. I want to take just a few Sheets as a separate Excel file ("Introduction_Page", "Observation_Overview", "ICS Analysis", "ICS Table").  In the one of  Sheets, namely  "Introduction_Page" there is a link to another sheet (value puts as a reference to another sheet), which is not copied to the new workbook. and, as a result, after saving, closing and opening again new file this value disappeared. How does resolve this issue?

Comment: yes i Need just to copy these Sheets to the separate file.